# Display custom attribute on category page

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, category-attribute

On our category page I want to echo an custom attribute with attribute code "homepage_description".

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
<?php echo $_product->getHomepageDescription() ?>
```

I also tried this:

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getHomepageDescription(), 'homepage_description') ?>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to edit attribute from **catalog->attributes->Manage Attributes** and open your attribute and change the below option to **Yes**:

[image: Its shows the option while edit the attribute]

Comment: Damn it, that did the trick! :)